# Monitor which SNMP communities are still in use

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, snmp, cisco-nexus

I am migrating from SNMP community1 to SNMP community2 on a NEXUS switch (plus a bunch of 2960s).

Is there a way to monitor that the old community is not used anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you need to do is to erase the old community, i know that sound like you haven´t doit before, but if you do that, and only configure the new one, and on your management or monitoring software, place the new one to, you will be sure that only the community2 is in use.

You are using cisco, i guess you can debug your snmp proccess:

```
your_router#debug snmp packet
your_router#debug snmp request
```

With snmp request, i think, you can have the community name what you are looking for. With snmp packet, you will get the source ip.

Comment: I don't won't to break the software that is using the old community: I want to make sure the old one is not useful to anyone.

Comment: Oh!!, you said that you dont know if someone is using the old community??, it is that??

Comment: yes, exactly. That is why I want to monitor the usage of the old one.

Comment: You need do a debbuging proccess to see wich community is in use. I edited my answer on the way to add more info.